# vb.net max Size of Elements in Array

Tags: excel, vb.net

In vb.net i implement an Excel formula, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. The returnvalue is a 2D object-array, which contains Strings. To print the returnvalue into multiple cells im using a matrix-formula.
Problem: If one of the Strings in the array has more then 255 letters, i get a #VALUE! error in every cell. Is that fixable or can i just bypass that?

Function in vb.net:  `Public Function multivalue() As Object`

Formula in Excel: `{=multivalue()}`

I also tried it in VBA, same error

```
Public Function testF() As Variant
    Dim Output(1, 1) As Object
    Output(0, 0) = 1
    Output(0, 1) = 2
    Output(1, 0) = 3
    Output(1, 1) = "String with over 255 letters: There are seven days of the week, or uniquely named 24-hour periods designed to provide scheduling context and make time more easily measureable. Each of these days is identifiable by specific plans, moods, and tones. Monday is viewed by many to be the worst day of the week, as it marks the return to work following the weekend, when most full-time employees are given two days off."
    testF = Output
EndFunction
```

Comment: After correcting your VBA code (`Output` should be of type `Variant`), I cannot reproduce your problem in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VBA code has some errors.
Your VBA code returns the `#VALUE!` error to the worksheet because you are trying to assign contents to an `Object` as if it were an array.  The error comes from this line:  `Output(0,0) = 1`

- `Output` could be either of type `Variant` or type `String`
- `Output` and `testF` need to be of the same type.

The following works as expected:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function testF() As String()
    Dim Output(1, 1) As String
    Output(0, 0) = 1
    Output(0, 1) = 2
    Output(1, 0) = 3
    Output(1, 1) = "String with over 255 letters: There are seven days of the week, or uniquely named 24-hour periods designed to provide scheduling context and make time more easily measureable. Each of these days is identifiable by specific plans, moods, and tones. Monday is viewed by many to be the worst day of the week, as it marks the return to work following the weekend, when most full-time employees are given two days off."
    testF = Output
End Function
```

or

```
Option Explicit
Public Function testF() As Variant
    Dim Output(1, 1) As Variant
    Output(0, 0) = 1
    Output(0, 1) = 2
    Output(1, 0) = 3
    Output(1, 1) = "String with over 255 letters: There are seven days of the week, or uniquely named 24-hour periods designed to provide scheduling context and make time more easily measureable. Each of these days is identifiable by specific plans, moods, and tones. Monday is viewed by many to be the worst day of the week, as it marks the return to work following the weekend, when most full-time employees are given two days off."
    testF = Output
End Function
```